# How can I make all images within separate divs stop overflowing?

Tags: html, css

I have one image using flexbox in the upper right corner of the webpage.  During mouseover, the image overflows onto the image to the left. I want to prevent that.   Also, if there is a way to make the image zoom out a bit in general.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

I have tried overflow: hidden and it seems to work on each image but the top right.

Here is a codepen example to see the animation https://codepen.io/dev20tx/pen/zXgRQj

```css
.grid-item-1, .grid-item-2, .grid-item-3, .grid-item-4 {
overflow: hidden;
width: 50%;
height: auto;
z-index: 0;
}

.grid-item-1, .grid-item-2, .grid-item-3, .grid-item-4 img {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
-ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
-o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.grid-item-1:hover, .grid-item-2:hover, .grid-item-3:hover, .grid- 
item-4:hover img {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.08); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:scale(1.08); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:scale(1.08); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:scale(1.08); /* Opera */
 transform:scale(1.08);
}

.work {
  height: 50vh;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
}

.contact {
  height: 50vh;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="work">
 <div class="grid-item grid-item-1"><img 
src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1803024/pexels-photo- 
1803024.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></div>
 <div class="grid-item grid-item-2"><img 
src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1555313/pexels-photo- 
1555313.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></div>
</div>
  
<div class="contact">
 <div class="grid-item grid-item-3"><img 
src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/300857/pexels-photo- 
300857.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></div>
 <div class="grid-item grid-item-4"><img 
src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2062080/pexels-photo- 
2062080.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be appreciated, if you can share a live code snippet.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dev20tx/pen/zXgRQj

Comment: you were simply just not targeting the correct elements, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images very getting overlapped, so I basically added the image to the background property, hope it helps.

Solution:

```css
.grid-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* [1.2] Hide the overflowing of child elements */
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.grid-item-1 {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1803024/pexels-photo-1803024.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2062080/pexels-photo-2062080.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.grid-item-3 {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1555313/pexels-photo-1555313.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.grid-item-4 {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/300857/pexels-photo-300857.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.grid-item:hover .grid-item-1,
.grid-item:hover .grid-item-2,
.grid-item:hover .grid-item-3,
.grid-item:hover .grid-item-4 {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-item-1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-item-2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-item-3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="grid-item-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following CSS classes and selectors to get the desired effect where no part of the image/div is overflowing another one. You were targeting the divs and not the images in the majority of your css selectors

```
.grid-item-1, .grid-item-2, .grid-item-3, .grid-item-4 {
overflow: hidden;
width: 50%;
height: auto;
z-index: 0;
}

.grid-item-1 img, .grid-item-2 img, .grid-item-3 img , .grid-item-4 img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
-ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
-o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
transition: all 1s ease;
-webkit-transform:scale(1.00); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:scale(1.00); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:scale(1.00); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:scale(1.00); /* Opera */
 transform:scale(1.00);
}

.grid-item-1:hover img, .grid-item-2:hover img, .grid-item-3:hover img, .grid-item-4:hover img {
-webkit-transform:scale(1.08); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:scale(1.08); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:scale(1.08); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:scale(1.08); /* Opera */
 transform:scale(1.08);
}
```

**Explanation**:

In your code you were not targeting the image correctly, the following

`.grid-item-1, .grid-item-2, .grid-item-3, .grid-item-4 img`

only targets the last image `.grid-item-4 img`, where as the other styles would have only been applied to the div level `.grid-item-3` , so change it to my selector

`grid-item-1 img, .grid-item-2 img, .grid-item-3 img , .grid-item-4 img`

The same applies to your hover selector.

Comment: This definitely helps, thank you.  Is there a way to do this and make it responsive?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve when you say you want it to be responsive?

Comment: I guess what I mean is going from desktop to mobile size without the pictures becoming messed up.  What finally worked for me was adding the images to the background instead.